# mySQL Average Difference between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, min, datediff

Can anyone help me on this query? I'm looking at an accommodation_offer.created_at and at booking.requested_at for the difference between the first and the minimum result found for the second.

I'm getting an Unknown column 'minbooking' in 'field list' error

i've created minbooking as I initially believed having a nested select would help with the AVG(DATEDIFF(MIN( query I had initially. Since then I've removed the nested Select and have been trying this way with yet no success.

By the way, an offer can have multiple bookings. I'm looking to have results grouped by city, then by offer created date and then showing the average time difference between offer created and first booking of each offer.

```
SELECT
accommodation_offer.created_at_month AS "Month of Offer Created",
property.address_city_code AS "City",
MIN(booking.requested_at) AS minbooking,
AVG(DATEDIFF(minbooking,accommodation_offer.created_at)) AS "Time Span in     Days"
FROM booking
INNER JOIN accommodation_offer
ON accommodation_offer.id=booking.offer_id
INNER JOIN property
ON accommodation_offer.property_id=property.id
GROUP BY property.address_city_code, accommodation_offer.created_at_month
ORDER BY property.address_city_code, accommodation_offer.created_at_month ASC
```

Comment: ,You can't directly mention one alias for another column in select statement (In your exa. you used alias 'minbooking' in other column "Time Span in     Days")

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
accommodation_offer.created_at_month AS "Month of Offer Created",
property.address_city_code AS "City",
MIN(booking.requested_at) AS minbooking,
AVG(DATEDIFF(MIN(booking.requested_at),accommodation_offer.created_at_month)) AS  
"Time Span in     Days"
FROM booking
INNER JOIN accommodation_offer
ON accommodation_offer.id=booking.offer_id
INNER JOIN property
ON accommodation_offer.property_id=property.id
GROUP BY property.address_city_code, accommodation_offer.created_at_month
ORDER BY property.address_city_code, accommodation_offer.created_at_month 
ASC
```

Comment: Thanks Raj, this returns my first error that led me to try and split the AVG(DATEDIFF(MIN initially    "Invalid use of group function"

Comment: Hi Raj, what i'm saying is that it still returns me an error... "Invalid use of group function"

Comment: in alias  "Time Span in     Days"  replace "accommodation_offer.created_at" this by '"accommodation_offer.created_at_month"

Comment: so, in the Accommodation Offers DB we have both created_at and created_at_month, hence the use

Comment: so u can't use it directly in select statement without including it in group by  you need to include it in group by or use MIn(),MAX() Or SUM() or functions like this with accommodation_offer.created_at

Comment: still same error... 
GROUP BY booking.requested_at, property.address_city_code, accommodation_offer.created_at_month, accommodation_offer.created_at